# How to covert integer number into datetime?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have a integer number 50 which is saved in my database as duration
and I want to convert it into a datetime.

I have used `Time.at(50)` and it gives the result

```
1970-01-01 05:30:50 +0530
```

At the date place I want zero value.

Comment: If it is a duration, why do you want to convert it to DATETIME? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: When you convert it, the time is taken as 50 seconds past 'the epoch', which was 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00 (UTC), which is 1970-01-01 05:30:00 IST.  So the returned value is entirely correct; it is 50 seconds after the reference time in your local time zone.  If you want something else, you need to do a different conversion.  In particular, durations (aka INTERVAL in standard SQL) are related to, but different from and not commensurate with, TIME or TIMESTAMP (collectively DATETIME) types. (It seems that MySQL does not support INTERVAL types — well, neither does DB2, but it's a little odd.)

Comment: Thanks Devart, I need this date time format in my XML file. At Duration place i have to represent it in datetime.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, what kind of different conversion i need to do?

Comment: Agree with Vash answer - this duration should be added to specified datetime. Because duration is just a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have a zero in the date portions; if you could it would not be a date anymore.

You must to have some start point, and this start point was settled to 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC.

[The history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: Thanks Vash, Can it be possible or not?

Comment: @SumitMunot, see  Jonathan Leffler comment. It can not be possible for date type, it can be done for TIME. That if you do not want date part it should meet your expectation.

Comment: But date part is very necessary as per my need.

Comment: So think about `1970-01-01` as zero or declare some date value that you will add the duration later.

Comment: If i considered the date as zero and adding the duration in it then it will be converted in to string but what i need is the datetime format for my XML.